# iPhone: Manage frameworks according to ios versions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my iPad App,

I have done coding for twitter.

For ios version 4.0,4.1,4.2 and 4.3.

And

ios version 5.0.

```
I have done separate coding for twitter.


if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=5.0)
```

like this.

The problem is when I run the code in ios 4.x it crashes

**with result could not load the twitter framework that I include in XCode.**

So, How do I manage this frameworks in my app.

It's Deployement Target is 4.0.

It's Base SDK is 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check that the Twitter.framework is linked "optional". Go to You Target, choose "Bild Phases", select "Link Binary With Libraries" and selection "Optional" at the Twitter.framework.

Check screenshot:

[image]

The in you code, you can check if the Twitter Framework is here by calling:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"TWRequest") != NULL) {
  // Yes. Twitter Framework loaded
}
```