# Adding QuartzCore to project when deployment target is 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an app and the deployment target is 4.2. I need to use QuartzCore but when I'm trying to add it to "Link Binary With Libraries" I can only use the 5.0 SDK.

Can I use the 5.0 or am I supposed to get the QuartzCore for 4.2 from somewhere?

Comment: Did you try weak (optional) linking?

You might check [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136922/iphone-manage-frameworks-according-to-ios-versions/10136991#10136991

Comment: Optional means it won't link for lower (than 5.0) versions, but I still need that framework.

Comment: But QuartzCore is available since iOS 2.0! So you might pick the wrong .fraemwork folder?

Comment: So I need to find the quartzcore for ios 4.2 ?

Comment: If you picketed the right location Xcode should automatically chance this packaged according to your build settings. Try to delete and add QuartzCore again.